# Ethernet data transfer between FPGA-PC

Tags: networking, udp, ethernet

I am developing a logic core to perform data transfer between a FPGA and a PC over ethernet, using a LAN8710 PHY on my FPGA board.

I've achieved to transfer some UDP data packets from the FPGA to the PC. It's a simple core that complies with the PHY transfer requirements. It builds the UDP package and transfer it to the PC.

To check the reception on the PC, I am using Wireshark and as said above, I receive the packets correctly. I've checked the reception with a simple UDP receiver written by myself.

But, I've noticed that I only receive these packets when Wireshark is running on the PC. I mean, if Wireshark is ON, my application receives the packets too, and the counter of received packets of the following picture increases. (This picture is not mine, just one from the internet)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsChT.gif

If I close Wireshark, the PC stops receiving packets and the counter of received packets stops. My application stops receiving too.

1. Although novice on networking topics, I suspect that this issue is related to PC-side. Seems like Wireshark is "opening/closing" the ethernet communication channel, or something like that. Does anyone knows about this issue?
2. To build a functional core to transfer data between a PC and the FPGA, I've developed a core to transfer and receive UDP packets. Next step will be ARP implementation (to let the PC identify my FPGA board, as I understand). What protocols are necessary to perform full-duplex data transfer between this 2 devices?

Thank you very much in advance,

migue.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are able to get appropriate receive interrupt at ethernet driver level on PC-side for a single transmitted packet by FPGA. If you do not get the receive interrupt, check on the transmit side(FPGA) for appropriate transmit interrupts for packet that is being transmitted. This should mostly help you in cornering the issue.

As far as i know, wireshark is just a packet analyzer/sniffer. However, if wireshark is suspected, one option could be to try with alternate packet sniffer to rule out if any such scenario is happening.

A handy tool for determining problems in network and also for determining the network statistics shall be netstat. **netstat -sp udp** shall list down the statistics only for UDP. There are many other parameters that can be used with netstat for diagnosis.

Comment: Thank for your response Karthik. How can I check the receive interrupt on the PC-side?

Comment: It depends on your processor & design. Accordingly, you may need check the respective interrupt counters or have your own counters or have debug logs.

Answer (score 1):

After many months I solved it, I post to help someone stucked in the same point.

Finally I figured out that Wireshark uses a tool to access the network link layer of the computer. This tool allows Wireshark to sniff all incoming and outgoing packets at a specified network device. To do this, the first step is to OPEN the network device, and that's why my program only worked if Wireshark was open.

Regards.