# FPGA and PC ethernet connection

Tags: linux, tcp, udp, fpga, ethernet

I want to connect fpga board's ethernet to PC's ethernet directly and do data transfer in both directions. I am confused on how to setup this.

> - Should I use Raw ethernet frames between FPGA and PC? But I could not find any windows application to send/capture raw frames. Can I do this in linux or something?
> - What would be the IP addresses and MAC addresses of PC and FPGA board in such a direct connection? How to find it? As there is no LAN or something involved here, I don't know how IP addresses get assigned to them.
> - Should I use TCP/IP or UDP in direct connection instead of raw frames? It seems to complicate FPGA side. I am not sure.
> - Is it better to have FPGA board and PC on same LAN, instead of direct connection. Again can I use raw frames or should I go for TCP/IP or UDP?
> - Is it necessary to implement ARP on FPGA, if I go for TCP/IP or UDP?

Comment: One question at a time.  Also, if you're asking a question like, "what would the IP address of the FPGA board be?", you need to go read a network primer.

Comment: I am from electronics. So I am not sure about these things. Anyway I posed this question after reading and surfing, not as a blindly ignorant student. All I understood is if there is some network involved like LAN, all devices in that network will be assigned an IP address by the server. In direct ethernet connection, I don't see such things as LAN or server involved here. So the concept of IP address is still there ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Maybe even [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I found a lot of questions on FPGA and ethernet in stack overflow like -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824402/ethernet-data-transfer-between-fpga-pc

Comment: IF 2 PCs are directly connected thru ethernet then both will get some definite IP addresses. No need of any LAN with DHCP server to get IPs. But I am doubtful about how to resolve the IP address of the FPGA Board in FPGA-PC connection. You will get some idea here: https://superuser.com/questions/1005693/getting-ip-address-of-a-direct-connected-computer

Comment: Thank You for your help and time :-). I think IP address is not much of an importance if there is no TCP/IP or UDP is involved. Only MAC address is relavant. @MITURAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Better choose a Network Layer Protocol over raw frames. I think the best way is UDP. It has simple header and less complexity compared to TCP/IP. It's popularly used in communication between FPGA and host PC. Examples are found in internet. Connect FPGA to same network as PC, so that DHCP Server will assign an IP address to FPGA. ARP is not necessary, if you know the MAC address of FPGA board. Usually it is written on the board itself. Also an eg: in Xilinx, we can configure MAC in code itself. It is safe as long as no other device uses the same MAC in the network.

Comment: @MeenieLeis - There are other exchanges in the Stack Exchange network. There's [over 170 of them](https://stackexchange.com/). Perhaps you should ask your hardware integration questions on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I found a lot of questions on FPGA and ethernet in stack overflow like -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824402/ethernet-data-transfer-between-fpga-pc